# How do I recover/kill an SSH session after losing connection?

Tags: ssh, networking

I lost my connection while I was logged via SSH into my university server. Classic.

Now I can't log in since the session appears to be still running and 
I get the error "Too many logins for 'myuser'". (Only 1 login for each user is allowed)

Is there a way to recover the session *not* having another access to the server (I can't reach any sysadmin until monday) - or the only way is just to wait for the session to time out? 
Typically how long should I wait? More than an hour has already passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try running something like `ssh -n remuser remhost kill -HUP -1`.  This would not create a login, so it *might* bypass the 1 login/user limitation.

If this does not work, then you might have to find someone who does have access, then run `su remuser` with your password from that person's account.  Then you'd be able to run `kill -HUP -1`.

Comment: I'd also suggest trying to get someone else to 'talk username' to try and trigger network traffic for the session which should cause it to timeout, if su doesn't work.