# Kill ssh session in screen from client side

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, session

I connected to an SSH server and left a script running using `screen`. After that, I logged out.

Now, about 10 hours later and after a reboot of the client, I can't connect to the server anymore. After I input my password, nothing happens for 1 or 2 minutes, then I get:

`packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe`

I tried running what [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20453/164427) said, the command:

```
ssh -n username@server server kill -HUP -1
```

But I get the same error message. What else can I do?

Here is what I get if I try to connect with the `-vvv`

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/username/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<server_name>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <server_name> [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <server_name>:22 as 'remote_username'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <server_name>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<hidden digest, don't know if it's save to make public>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <server_name>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host '<server_name>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:15
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (<12 digit hex nr>)
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
remote_username@server_name's password: <here is where I input the password>
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to <server_name> ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network      <after this line, nothing shows for 1 or 2 minutes>
debug3: send packet: type 1
packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the details from running: `ssh -vvv <login@server>`? If needed, hide the IP with `xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz`.

Comment: Unless screen is your shell on the remote side, this probably has nothing to do with it. Can you log in at all? What is the command you use to login? What does `ssh -v -v` say?

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm sorry, what do you mean by "screen is your shell on the remote side"? I ran `screen` in the server, not the client, if that's what you're wondering. Then I detached from the screen and disconnected from the server. I tried to login immediately after, just to test, and it worked. I am thinking screen keeps a session running even if the client loses connection, and that along with some kind of timeout might have caused this.

Comment: There's a problem either with the server or with a network hop. It's unrelated to screen: you're getting blocked during the login process. [A search on `pledge: network`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ssh%22+%22pledge%3A+network%22) points to LDAP authentication as a likely culprit, e.g. [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/792486/ssh-connection-takes-forever-to-initiate-stuck-at-pledge-network) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340309/ssh-7-4-prolonged-pause-at-pledge-network).